# How to bend/curve a image in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

i have this [image]

i want to do this

[image]

[image]

to

[image]

HTML

```
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

JS

```
var temp_can1, temp_can1_ctx;
$(document).ready(function () {
temp_can1 = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
temp_can1_ctx = temp_can1.getContext('2d');
var imageObj_rotator3 = new Image();

imageObj_rotator3.onload = function () {

    temp_can1_ctx.drawImage(imageObj_rotator3, 0, 0);
    temp_can1_ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
    var pattern = temp_can1_ctx.createPattern(imageObj_rotator3, 'no-repeat');
    temp_can1_ctx.rect(0, 0, temp_can1.width, temp_can1.height);
    temp_can1_ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
    temp_can1_ctx.fill();
    temp_can1_ctx.globalAlpha = 0.10;
    temp_can1_ctx.drawImage(imageObj_rotator3, 0, 0);
    temp_can1_ctx.drawImage(imageObj_rotator3, 0, 0);
    temp_can1_ctx.drawImage(imageObj_rotator3, 0, 0);

};
imageObj_rotator3.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8EJp.png';

});
```

[Here is my JSFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/tahmid/fLkaU/)
[Updated JSFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/tahmid/fLkaU/1/)

is this possible to do in html5 canvas. if possible then show me some direction/example.

Thank you

Comment: -1 : is posting several times the same question, and even worse  without having any clue of the answer, a good behaviour ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427293/how-to-paint-a-continuous-circular-pattern-with-html5-canvas

Comment: Check this. It is using a parabola equation to find y position. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251177/curving-an-image-that-starts-as-a-rectangle-uploaded-by-user-preferably-using/29118400#29118400

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible using any native Canvas transformations as your stretched output requires *non-affine* transformations.  i.e. it cannot be achieved simply by combining rotations, translations, etc.

Ideally you need to define a formula mapping to the original cartesian coordinates from the distorted coordinate system and then iterate over the destination pixel space, using the above mapping to determine the required colour for that pixel.

You would also need to interpolate neighbouring pixels to avoid the output looking "blocky".

This is non-trivial...

Comment: Understatement of the year: "This is non-trivial..."

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It's possible, but it doesn't seem practical for your project.

You can using a perspective slicing technique:

http://www.subshell.com/en/subshell/blog/image-manipulation-html5-canvas102.html

You can also "fake" non-affine transforms. This generally involves:

1. Dividing your image into rectangles,
2. Diagonally bisecting those rectangles into triangles.
3. Warping those triangles to form the desired distortion--a distortion wireframe.
4. For each triangle: pixel-interpolating the original image from the undistorted triangle into the distorted triangle to achieve warp distortion.

Comment: page not available anymore.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you'll need WebGL. You'll have to take the image you want to distort, use it as a texture and map it on a curved surface.