# drawImage() in fabric js

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

How to rewrite the following code with fabric js?

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
```

While using fabric js, it is not returning the context. Is there any way to return the context? I tried following code.

```
var fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(ccr.options.candleCanvasId);
fabricCanvas.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
```

But it gave me an error "fabricCanvas.drawImage is not a function".
How can I use the drawImage() with fabric js?

**Edit**

Using clipTo() in fabric js allows to achieve the crop functionality. But I want to modify the image shape. Check this link. [How to bend/curve a image in html5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428355/how-to-bend-curve-a-image-in-html5-canvas) . Here it is done by re drawing the image by changing the destination x and y positions. Is there any option in fabric js to get the context to use html5's default functions? Or is there any equivalent function for drawImage() ?

Answer (score 4):

You do not draw an image. You give the image to fabric and let fabric draw it. Example: http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1#images

```
var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
  left: dx,
  top: dy,
  width: dwidth,
  height: dheight,
  clipTo: function (ctx) {
    ctx.rect(dwidth / 2 - sx, dheight / 2 - sy, swidth, sheight);
  }
});
fabricCanvas.add(imgInstance);
```

Comment: I need to crop an image from a source image. Check this link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage. Similar thing i need to do with fabric js.

Comment: I added an untested example, as I cannot test at the moment. (Not on my own laptop)

Comment: ClipTo() can be use for cropping. But if I need to modify the image shape? check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428355/how-to-bend-curve-a-image-in-html5-canvas

Comment: Then you should create a new question for that.

Comment: URL should be: http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1#images